# Decompositions of a compact Lie group into "fixed point set types"

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Consider a compact Lie group $G$ which acts on a closed Riemannian manifold $M$ by isometries. Then it is well-known that there are only finitely many *isotropy types* of the $G$-action, i.e. finitely many non-isomorphic conjugacy classes of isotropy groups. The isotropy types correspond to orbit types, and $M$ decomposes into a disjoint union of smooth submanifolds

$M=\bigsqcup_{i=1}^N M_i$,

where $M_i$ denotes the union of all orbits of type $i$. Furthermore, one knows that there is a *principal isotropy type* $i_p$ such that $M_{i_p}$ is connected, open and dense in $M$. This way, the $G$-action leads to a "nice" geometric decomposition of $M$.

Now, for $g\in G$, let $F_g\subset M$ be the set of fixed points of the isometry $M\to M$ corresponding to $g$. Then each connected component of $F_g$ is a closed, totally geodesic submanifold of $M$, see Kobayashi, *Transformation Groups in Differential Geometry*, Theorem 5.1. Of course, $F_g$ may be empty or, for example in the case $g=e$ (the neutral element), $F_e=M$.

Call two fixed point sets $F_g$, $F_{g'}$ equivalent if their connected components are diffeomorphic (in particular, the number of connected components must be the same). Call an equivalence class $[F_g]$ under this equivalence relation a *fixed point set type*. Then we can speak of the fixed point set type of a group element $g$, and we obtain the family of distinct fixed point set types

$I:=\{[F_g],\; g\in G\}$.

- **Question 1**: How large can $I$ be? Obviously, $|I|\leq |G|$. Do examples $(M,G)$ exist where $I$ is in fact (uncountably) infinite? I can think only of examples where $I$ is finite.
- **Question 2**: For $i\in I$, set $G_i=\{g\in G, \text{ the fixed point set type of }g \text{ is }i\}$. Is $G_i\subset G$ a smooth submanifold?
- **Question 3**: Under the assumption that $G$ acts effectively, is there a *principal fixed point set type* $i_p$ such that $G_{i_p}$ is dense in $G$ (and open and connected)?

In total, the questions ask how "nice" the decomposition

$G=\bigsqcup_{i\in I} G_i$

is. The idea is that it might be "dual" in some sense to the decomposition of $M$ into orbit types.

Thank you in advance for your answers and comments.

---

**EDIT: To start with, it would already be great to have a reference to a book or an article which considers the family of fixed point sets of the individual isometries in an isometric action of a compact Lie group on a closed Riemannian manifold.**

Of course, nearly every book about Lie group actions treats fixed point sets of the whole group action. On the other hand, there are many books which treat single isometries of Riemannian manifolds and their fixed point sets. But none of those resources seem really useful to answer my questions above.

---

Comment: A little step in the direction of your edit is theorem 29.19 of http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf